# How to add notification in list whenever new notification received in vue ionic?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, push-notification, vuejs3

In my app when i receive new notification I want to render it notifications component . Now problem is It is not necessary that I always have opened that component on my screen. maybe I am on another component but when I want to see notification whenever I open that component. I am receiving real time notification in my main.js file.

```
PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived',
async (notification) => {
 //Notification 
}
);
```

This file is available globally

There is component `Notification` In this Component i have list of notification i want to render that notification in this list.
Is this possible?

Here is component notification

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Notifications</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button menuId="custom" auto-hide="false"></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons slot="primary">
          <ion-button color="secondary" @click="handleSignOut">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" :icon="logOut"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons slot="primary"> </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
      <ion-header collapse="condense">
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title size="large">Notifications</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-title>{{ msg }}</ion-title>
      <ion-list v-if="this.notifications.length > 0">
        <ion-item
          v-for="(notification, index) in this.notifications"
          :key="index"
         >
          <ion-label @click="() => router.push(`${notification.data.actionURL}`)">
            
            {{ notification.data.actionText }}
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
     
     
      <ion-toolbar v-else>
        <ion-title size="large" align="center">No Notification</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>

    
      
    </ion-content>
    <side-menu />
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import {
  IonPage,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonTitle,
  IonContent,
  IonIcon,
  IonButtons,
  IonButton,
  IonList,
  IonItem,
  IonLabel,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import { logOut } from "ionicons/icons";

import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import SideMenu from "./SideMenu.vue";
import { TokenService } from "@/services/token.service";
export default {
  name: "Tab1",
  components: {
    IonHeader,
    IonToolbar,
    IonTitle,
    IonContent,
    IonPage,
    IonIcon,
    IonButtons,
    IonButton,

    IonList,
    IonItem,
    IonLabel,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "",
      notifications: {},

    };
  },

  
   
  },
   mounted(){
       this.notifications= TokenService.getUserInfo().unread_notifications
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Vuex could be a good option here, especially if the application grows and you want to manage app state.

Comment: Can you please provide any example?

Comment: If you opt for vuex, then I would suggest to just dig into the documentation where everything is explained, also with code samples: https://vuex.vuejs.org/